# How to choose an assay for detecting virulence factors?

Tags: immunology, lab-techniques, assay-development

When looking for a protein of interest, an ELISA is being administered. I read this [article](https://www.bio-rad-antibodies.com/elisa-types-direct-indirect-sandwich-competition-elisa-formats.html) about the different types of ELISAs and the advantages/disadvantages.

However, I am conflicted about whether a sandwich ELISA or a direct ELISA would be best detecting a protein virulence factor in a serum sample. The thought behind the sandwich was the antigen would not need to be purified before measuring.

Any advice as to choosing an ELISA for the detection of a specific virulence protein?